# Rails 4 production assets not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The digest strings in the assets are different from what gets generated in my html so I get 404s.

In my HTML I have...

```
/assets/application-06017e7a13d3357bb1886bb09c81a23caddf2643b4d1dde61dd9711c3eb128c2.css
```

My actual file in the assets folder looks like this...

```
application-2c1b3dd5c5b669b6cd1b31f4da0a41f3.css
```

Comment: Have you tried re-running `rake assets:clean && rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in both production and development mode.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Don't forget to restart the server :)